# Handheld Device and Web services

Tags: handheld

I am working on an C#.NET application for handheld devices with Windows CE 2003, these devices connect to a web service, hosted on a local web server, for connection to database.

Problem I am facing: I have to keep web service directory security as Anonymous because handheld device cant be authenticated from AD and thats why I cant use windows authenticated security settings.

Can anyone suggest me how do I ensure security of web service having anonymous security??

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to keep directory security as anonymous for pocket pcs to use the webservice, but we can control these permissions by granting access on the basis of IP addresses through IIS. For this just go to IIS and right click on web service folder and go to properties. Then in derectory security tab, IP address and domain name restrictions section provides this functionality of restricting users on the basis of their IP or domain.

I hope it will help others too.

Cheers.